# The import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, objectmapper

I'm trying to create a JSON file and i'm having trouble while trying to use ObjectMapper class. heres my class code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import desafiodimensiva.entities.Desafio2;

@RestController
public class Desafio2Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/teste")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/desafio2")
    public Desafio2 novoDesafio2() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Desafio2 pessoa = new Desafio2();
        BigDecimal valorFinanceiroPessoa = new BigDecimal("0.00");
        pessoa.setNomePessoa("-----------                            ");
        pessoa.setIdPessoa("0000");
        pessoa.setValorFinanceiro(valorFinanceiroPessoa);

        return pessoa;
    }
}
```

and there's my pom.xml :

```
`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.desafio.dimensiva</groupId>
    <artifactId>desafiodimensiva</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Desafio Dimensiva</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5-pre3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>desafiodimensiva</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>



</project>`
```

I cannot import ObjectMapper class even with the `jackson-databind` dependency added at the `pom.xml` file. and the jars `jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar, jackson-core-2.9.5.jar, jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar` are at the classpath.

Comment: Just remove this dependency... check your dependency tree `mvn dependency:tree` and you ll find multiple ones... it comes with spring boot starter web especially the version you are using!

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`. This should clean everything and might solve the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the version for jackson  dependency `jackson-databind` i.e. just write

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

in your `pom.xml`. And let spring-boot decide the version for you.

Feel free to remove the jars from classpath.

Comment: please mention the location of pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
 <dependency>                                         
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>    
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>        
    <version>2.9.0</version> <--- remove this
 </dependency>
```

Also take a look into the effective pom by **right clicking pom.xml** if you are on intellij **Maven > Show Effective POM** . Check for conflicts there.

```
 <dependency>                                         
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>    
 </dependency>
```

and then try

```
 mvn dependency:purge-local-repository;
```

This will first resolve the entire dependency tree, then delete the contents from the local repository, and then re-resolve the dependencies from the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution did not work for me. If you are still facing this issue then alternative solution is to add following dependency-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.datatype.jsr310.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Kindly upvote this solution, if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding in Kotlin, add this into your build.gradle.kts (Module :app) then sync your gradle:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.3")
```